# ¿Validar DNI, CIF y NIE (España) en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Base de datos: `reservas_programacion`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `reservas_vip`
--

CREATE TABLE `reservas_vip` (
  `numReserva` int(31) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL CHECK (`numReserva` > 0), 
  `dniCliente` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `nombreHotel` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `destinoReserva` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `extrasReserva` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `precioReserva` double NOT NULL CHECK (`precioReserva` > 0)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Y desearia que a la hora de insertar en la base de datos, el motor (en este caso uso XAMPP con MYSQL) me compare y me valide la columna del **dniCliente**. Desearía que pueda admitir:

1. CIF
2. DNI
3. NIE

He intentado con REGEX_LIKE (Que en la documentación de oracle y de mysql 8.0 se encuentra) y no he obtenido éxito, con REGEX solo me deja uno solo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final indagando y sin encontrar éxito he podido encontrar una solución un problema que tuve recientemente. Resulta que la manera de trabajar con las expresiones regulares es distinta de la de Mysql a la de Oracle y por eso tenía conflicto.

La versión de **Mysql (Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.18-MariaDB)** que tengo permite REGEXP pero no REGEXP_LIKE (una pena), pero igualmente, como he visto que me permite comparar expresiones regulares en una línea lo único que he añadido es un OR y otra expresión regular, por ejemplo en un DNI.

Por ejemplo validar esa columna para que admita CIF, DNI y NIE.

Tengo el siguiente código de una base de datos de un ejercicio que me mandaron posterior a este:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Base de datos: `reservas_programacion`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `reservas_vip`
--

CREATE TABLE `reservas_vip` (
  `numReserva` int(31) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL CHECK (`numReserva` > 0), 
  `dniCliente` varchar(9) NOT NULL CHECK (
        `dniCliente` REGEXP '^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]'
        OR `dniCliente` REGEXP'^[KLMXYZ][0-9]{7}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]'
        OR `dniCliente` REGEXP '^[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]{1}[0-9]{8}'
    ),
  `nombreHotel` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `destinoReserva` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `extrasReserva` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `precioReserva` double NOT NULL CHECK (`precioReserva` > 0)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Lo que he explicado anteriormente lo hago por ejemplo en la columna dniCliente, valido si es NIF,CIF o NIE (3 en 1). Lo que no pude es darle nombres a las restricciones, tengo que investigar más eso.

Espero a alguien le ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Teneis un ejemplo para SQL SERVER en esta URL: (PARA nie extranjeros no sirve)

https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/SQL-Server/1469470-Funcion-Validar-CIF_NIF_NIE.html#last